# PHP and CSS font-face doesn't work

Tags: php, css, font-face, custom-font

Im currently making a poll website. And i were trying to change the font **(to a custom font(font-face))** of the **h1** tag but it doesn't work. But changing the color and everything else works. I have also tried changing the tag to **p** and giving it an **id**. The custom font works on all other pages but the poll php one.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: Ubuntu-BI;
 src: url('fonts/Ubuntu-BI.ttf');
}
```

---

```
h1{
 color: #e9e9e9;
 font-family: Ubuntu-BI;
 font-size: 40px;
}
```

---

```
<style>
  <?php include 'css/pollStyle.css'; ?>
</style>
<?php <!-- HERE'S THE REST OF THE CODE
```

---

```
echo "<h1>$title</h1>";  //< Title of the pole
```

---

I would really appreciate some help! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the CSS itself, the problem must lay in the way it is included. As per miken32 answer you should use a link tag to attach the stylesheet. In theory the way you have specified would work as long as this code was within the `<head></head>` tags.

Comment: I've done it now, but it seems to not work. The PHP is within the body tag.

Comment: Can you try moving <style>
  <?php include 'css/pollStyle.css'; ?>
</style> to within the head tag

Comment: Even if this works you should still use a link tag to attach the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) construct does not output anything to the page. It includes the contents of a file into the current code base. What you want to do is put this into the HTML document head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pollStyle.css"/>
```